# How to create a typed python function that takes a generic `Literal` as input and has a return type that can be inferred as the same `Literal`?

Tags: python, types

I'd like to create a function that takes an input typed any arbitrary type with a generic (eg.`Literal["a", "b"] | None`) and returns the same type removing `None` if present. `Literal["a", "b"]`.

I'm not sure if it is possible to pass a `Literal` as a generic, and then get it back as a the same `Literal`, since even the most basic noop function I tried changed the `Literal["a", "b"]` to `str`

```py
TLiteralValue = TypeVar("TLiteralValue")
def return_same_type(input: TLiteralValue) -> TLiteralValue:
    return input

before: Literal["a", "b"] = "a"
after = return_same_type(before) # --> Inferred as `str`
```

Is it possible to make `after` be inferred as `Literal["a", "b"]`?

Notes: I'm using python 3.9, but I would like to know if this is possible on any version or using any library.

Comment: `Optional[TLiteralValue] -> TLiteralValue`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I would ultimately do that, but the issue here is that the output of the function is inferred as `str` and not as the `Literal["a","b"]` passed as input.